# $db->fetchAll($query) non-associative for loop through columns

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db

I'm been hunting everywhere trying to find how to access data returned via a Zend db call.  i want to append each columns value, comma delimited into a variable. I've always used associative calls in the past $row['fieldname'] etc.. but don't want to type out all the fields.  I think I'm pretty close with the below but it's not working.  Can someone point out my error?  Thanks!

```
$data = $db->fetchAll($query);
$i=13; //number of columns

foreach($data as $row){
for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
$csv_output .= $row[$j].", ";
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, you're over-complicating things! Try:

```
$csv_output = array();

foreach ($db->fetchAll($query) as $row)
{
    $csv_output[] = implode(', ', $row);
}

$csv_output = implode("\n", $csv_output);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv_output);
echo '</pre>';
```